# Poor performance when adding layer indexed ArcGIS Service layer to AGOL

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-online, sql-server, operations-dashboard

My data sits in enterprise geoddatabases on Windows Server 2012, SQL Server manager.

I often add ArcGIS Server Web services to my AGOL maps and they perform really well. However, when I add a specified indexed layer ID when adding the service, it drastically affects the performance of the layer. e.g:

https://xxx.xxx.com/xxxx/rest/services/xxx/xxx/MapServer/0

instead of:

https://xxx.xxx.com/xxxx/rest/services/xxx/xxx/MapServer

It's confusing me because the data is coming from the same source (same enterprise geodatabase, same server, same service), but performs a lot worse when added individually, rather than as a whole service.

The reason I want to add the layer individually, is because I use it in Operations Dashboard. However, when adding the whole service to a web map, I cannot get the map within Operations Dashboard to link/filter/query with the other chart elements via their actions tab "Element does not support any events". This functionality only becomes available to me if I reference the layer ID when adding the service to a web map, or upload and use AGOL hosted feature layers instead of service layers from my enterprise geodatabase.

I created spatial indexes which did not seem to help, but i doubt indexing should make a difference, when the same source works fine when adding the service as a whole.

Could anyone tell me:
a) What could be causing this big performance drop?
b) Any recommendations to rectifying/improving this performance?
c) An alternate way to get the Operations Dashboard functionality I am after in AGOL, using enterprise-sourced ArcGIS server layers?

Comment: When you load a layer from a MapServer with an index, the client load it with the FeatureLayer API. The client retrieve all the geometries and draw dynamically the data. If you load the MapServer without index, the client load it with the ArcGISDynamicLayer API, the server generate an image and the client draw the image on the browser. These are the different performances.